# AWS CloudFront website not being updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Our website hosted on CloudFront has not been updated for almost 24 hours now.

The CloudFront invalidation updated a few of the files. I can see on S3 all of the files have been updated. Performing a GET on these files I can see the timestamps are all correct *except* for one of the files (a javascript minified file called app.min.js) which still has an old timestamp on it. However, looking at S3, the app.min.js file has the correct updated timestamp. Forcing a no cache on the file, the app.min.js still reflects the old file.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what could be happening here?

Answer (score 2):

Your files are still being cached somewhere. If it's not cached in CloudFront, it may be cached in your browser or somewhere else between CloudFront and you.

Invalidating the CloudFront distribution does not invalidate the cache in your browser. So make sure you're using a fresh browser to test this. Better yet, use `curl`.

- Invalidate CloudFront again
- Restart your browser
- Use a different browser
- Use a different computer
- Use `curl` to avoid local caches

Do anything to eliminate the possibility of hitting a cached version.

Also:

1. Adding "no cache" to a file on S3 won't have any effect on the cached version in CloudFront. You'll need to invalidate the cache again to force CloudFront to get the new version.
2. The default TTL for CloudFront is 24 hours. So once it hits 24 hours, it should re-get the file from the origin. You can look at the headers to see how long it will be before the TTL runs out.

Comment: Thanks for help Matt. Ok I am still confused. Using `curl` we do get the latest version, yet through any browser and network (tried home/work computer and different browsers), the file is not updated.

Comment: Hmm, and curl fails to get the latest with the request header `Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br` The same request header that Chrome uses

Comment: Yah it could be double gzipping the file, testing now. I publish with awspublish npm package in gulp `.pipe(awspublish.gzip({ext: ''}))` and cloudfront might be gzipping again doh

Comment: If you are going to use CloudFront's compression then don't put compressed versions in S3.

Comment: Yah we had it turned off in cloudfront, trying to turn it on to automatically do it and turn it off during deploy, still testing.

Comment: Hmm yah still not working, cloudfront alias domain name works fine, it's just when we have our own domain in front of it (from route53) I think you are right, something cached in between, we just dont know what.

Comment: Ok it's working now. We invalidated with the wildcard /* and it worked, before we used an npm package that was invalidating individual files based on s3 state.